# Binary Trees Height and Complexity Correlation

Tags: tree, binary-tree, big-o, binary-search-tree

A lone node is a node without a sibling. A lone node's parent has no other child nodes.

If we define f(x) as:

(The number of lone nodes in binary tree x) / (Total nodes in x)

Is it true that height(x) is O(log n) if f(x) <= 0.5 ?

Comment: Please define "lone nodes"

Comment: Sorry, a lone node is a node without a sibling. The parent of the lone node has no other children nodes

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. Consider a totally unbalanced binary tree:

```
/\
 /\
  /\
   /\
    /\
     /\
      /\
```

There is only one "lone" node here, the root. (Not even clear if it is lone since it has no parent?) And the height is `O(n)`, not `O(log n)`.

Comment: Thanks Chris, however aren't all those nodes 'Lone' nodes, as none of them have siblings? They have children but that is irrelevant to the definition. Also you are correct on the assumption that the root is not a lone node as it has no parent

Comment: Well, according to your definition, I think all of them have siblings. Each of them (Except root) is either the left, or right, of a line like `/\\` in picture above. So the left is a sibling of the right, and the right is a sibling of the left. None of them is the only child of its parent. So according to definition you wrote, none of them is lone.

Comment: Another way to say it: Every node in the picture either has 0 children, or 2 children. A lone node can only happen if there is a node with exactly 1 children. So there are no lone nodes.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but in the textbook I'm reading, I get the feeling that they mean nodes on the same "level" of the tree. This is an exercise question in the textbook im reading for fun, the question is a "Why is this true" rather than a "Why or why not, explain"

Comment: Well, then I think you didn't understand the definitions precisely. This is the correct answer to the question you stated.

Comment: In the textbook it says " A lone node is a tree node without sibling (its parent has onlyone child branch)". In your example, all of your nodes are lone nodes

Comment: Every node in the picture has either 0 children, or 2 children. So none of them have only one child branch. I think you should try asking the question again if you aren't happy with the answer. It could be that your textbook has a mistake, or that it isn't written very carefully.

Comment: Oh sorry I was reading your diagram wrong, I interpreted it is a worst case degenerated list. So the situation you stated is worse than O(log n)? It doesnt seem to be as bad as O(n)

Comment: Well it has `2n+1` nodes and height `n+1`. (I guess you are right, it's only a maximally unbalanced tree, if you have the restriction that internal nodes must have 2 children, and you don't always assume that. Although in search trees usually you do.) So the height is definitely at least O(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
\
 \
 /\

n = 5
h(x) = 4
f(x) = 2/5 = 0.4 < 0.5
log(5)< 3 < 4 = h(x)
```

The example above is a counterexample to the claim that: 
if `f(x) <= 0.5` then `h(x) = O(log n)`:

There are 4 nodes (other than the root) 2 of which are "lone nodes" and the other two are not. This means that the condition `f(x) <= 0.5` is satisfied because `f(x) = 2/5 = 0.4 < 0.5`.

But if we'll check the height we'll see that it's 4 which is bigger than `log(5) = O(log n)`.